# add rtp header before aac adts header

Tags: rtp, aac

I was writing a program that could pack RTP header before h264 & aac. but I was confused with RTP timestamp field.

If the video codec is h264, the timestamp could be added by 90000/fps with each frame.
I have no idea about the aac.

My aac sample rate is 8000HZ,config=1588 and each frame is 250 ~ 520. I found some solution :

(1) 1024

(2) 8000/1024 = 7 => 8000/7 =  1142

Video and audio could not sync, the video will faster than audio.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Are you packing Audio payload ( AAC) and Video Payload ( H.264) in the same RTP packet or sending them separately, in different RTP packet ?  what are the RFC you are following.

Comment: I sent then in seperate rtp packet. RFC 6184 for H264 and RFC 3640 for mpeg4 audio(aac)
But I could not find the formula to calculate the timestamp for packing audio, I found some solution from website, like stack overflow or github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending/Transmitting of Packing RTP packets

H.264 @ 90000 - rtp timestamp = frame timestamp * 90000 (timestamp of the frame when read from any source)

AAC @ 8000 - rtp timestamp = buffer timestamp * 8000 (timestamp of the audio buffer when read from any source)

Receiving of unPacking RTP packets

H.264 - actual timestamp = rtp timestamp / 90000

AAC - actual timestamp = rtp timestamp / 8000

Based of the actual timestamp you do the Audio Video synchronization.

Note: convert the time to seconds from milliseconds

Comment: Hi, my h264 and aac both are raw data. How to calculate the frame timestamp & buffer timestamp ?
As I mentioned, I add 90000/fps for h264. But I have no idea about aac.

Comment: Video frames you can go with fps and calculate the interval/timestamp. Audio it is ptime , say for x milliseconds, you need to calculate the buffer time based on the sampling frequency of the Audio.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Could the formula for audio rtp timestamp be understood as ptime(milliseconds) / sample rate ?

Comment: yes you are right , make sure the unit conversions are correctly in place.